# command line arguments - int instead of ascii

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I'm writing a C++ console app and I cannot figure out how to have my command line arguments be interpreted as a number instead of ascii

```
int id = *argv[2];
if (id != 0)    //really, if a user enters "0", then id = 48 (0x30), not 0
{
    cout << "unknown product ID" << endl; endl;
    cout << "hit return to exit" << endl;
}
```

How is this sort of thing usually done?
Thanks

Comment: `int id = atoi(argv[2]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert the string to an integer.

```
int id = atoi(argv[2]);
// Or id = std::stoi(argv[2]), if you have C++11-standard compiler
// Or id = boost::lexical_cast<int>(argv[2]) if you have boost
```

Comment: VS 2010 throws an error, underlining argv
"Argument of type "_TCHAR*" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char*:

Comment: The underlying issue is that command line arguments are strings, not integers. `*argv[2]` means the first character of the string   pointed to by `argv[2]`. When Unicode is in use in Windows, the arguments are supplied as wide-character strings, which is why `stoi` works but `atoi` gives the error you saw.

Comment: Cool, how can I "get at" other characters of the same string? Is there a way of effectively doing *argv[2][n]?